# How to resolve undefined reference errors to threadIdx.x, blockDim.x, and blockIdx.x in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I'm a beginner working on a parallel list ranking algorithm in CUDA. I have no idea why I'm getting undefined reference errors to threadIdx.x, blockDim.x, and blockIdx.x, with the message "ld returned exit 1 status", when compiling with 'nvcc ParallelListRanking.cu -o ParallelListRanking'. Adding #include "device_launch_parameters.h" and #include "cuda.h" did not help. Any ideas to resolve this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__global__ void set_up(unsigned long int n, unsigned long int *dS, unsigned long long int *dQR){

        unsigned long int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

        if (i < n) {
                dS[i] = i + 1;
                dS[n-1] = 0;

                if (dS[i] != 0) {
                        dQR[i] = (dQR[i]%(1ull<<32)) + (1ull<<32) * 1ull;
                }
                else {
                        dQR[i] = (dQR[i]%(1ull<<32)) + (1ull<<32) * 0ull;
                }

                dQR[i] = ((unsigned long long int) dS[i])%(1ull<<32) + (1ull<<32)*(dQR[i]/(1ull<<32));
        }
}

__global__ void update(unsigned long int n, unsigned long long int *dQR) {

        unsigned long int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

        if (i < n) {
                unsigned long int tempdQ = (unsigned long int) (dQR[i]%(1ull<<32));
                unsigned long int tempdQQ = (unsigned long int) (dQR[tempdQ]%(1ull<<32));

                if (tempdQ != 0 && tempdQQ != 0) {
                        unsigned long long int tmpdQRQ = dQR[tempdQ];

                        unsigned long int tempdR = (unsigned long int) dQR[i]/(1ull<<32);
                        unsigned long long int tempdRQ = tmpdQRQ/(1ull<<32);

                        dQR[i] = ((unsigned long long int) tempdQQ)%(1ull<<32) + (((unsigned long long int) tempdR) + tempdRQ)*(1ull<<32);

                        tempdQ = tempdQQ;
                        tempdQQ = (unsigned long int) dQR[tempdQ]%(1ull<<32);
                }
        }
}

int main() {

        unsigned long int n = 1000;
        unsigned long int *dS =(unsigned long int *) cudaMalloc((int **)n, sizeof(unsigned long int));
        unsigned long long int *dQR = (unsigned long long int *) cudaMalloc((int **)n, sizeof(unsigned long long int));
        unsigned long int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

        set_up<<< 100, 100 >>>(n, dS, dQR);

        for (int t = 1; t < n; t++) {
                update<<< 100, 100>>>(n, dQR);
        }

        printf("%lu", (unsigned long int) (dQR[i]%(1ull<<32)));
        printf("\n");
        printf("%lu", (unsigned long int) (dQR[i]/(1ull<<32)));

        cudaFree(dQR);
        cudaFree(dS);

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this:

```
unsigned long int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
```

in host code (i.e. in `main()`).

Those variables are automatically defined in device code only (the routines decorated with `__global__`, for example).

The remainder of your host code from that point should not depend on variables like `threadIdx.x` because they are not defined in host code and make no sense to use there.

So just delete that line entirely (from `main()`) and come up with another method to use an index like that in your host code.

The only place you seem to use it is in your `printf` statements, so I guess if you are trying to print out all the variables you will need a loop in host code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%lu", (unsigned long int) (dQR[i]%(1ull<<32)));
    printf("\n");
    printf("%lu", (unsigned long int) (dQR[i]/(1ull<<32)));}
```

That is the proximal cause of the error you are reporting, however your code has other issues.

This is not correct usage of `cudaMalloc`:

```
    unsigned long int *dS =(unsigned long int *) cudaMalloc((int **)n, sizeof(unsigned long int));
```

you want to do something like this:

```
    cudaMallocManaged(&dS, sizeof(unsigned long int)*n);
```

and likewise for `dQR`.  (I'm switching from `cudaMalloc` to `cudaMallocManaged` here for a reason related to your attempt to print those variables from host code.)

There are likely other problems with your code.  Before attempting anything like this I would suggest you have a firm grasp of how to write a proper, simple vector add application in CUDA.

To get a basic grasp of CUDA you might want to study a simple sample code like `vectorAdd` and perhaps study one of [the introductory blogs](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/even-easier-introduction-cuda/).